# Scale and position image in Scribus

Tags: python, image, scribus

I am customizing the built-in CalendarWizard Python script in Scribus to add birthdays with pictures. I have the profile pictures in a folder for each person and I would like to save scale and position information for these pictures, so they are automatically applied when the calendar is generated.
The image box is created like:

```
 kep = createImage(self.marginl + colCnt * self.colSize,
                      self.calHeight + szovegsor + rowCnt * self.rowSize,
                      self.colSize, kepsor)
```

Then I fill the box with the photo:

```
szkep = 'C:\\profilepics\\' + sznapos + '.jpg'
kkep = loadImage(szkep,kep)
```

The sznapos variable contains the name of the current birthday person. So far we don't have multiple birthdays.
The next action would be to scale the loaded image. I can fit to the box:

```
setScaleImageToFrame(1, 1, kep)
```

This works.
But what I would like is to scale the image by a given value, but I am not sure how.
Tried, first with static values 2 ways:

```
setImageScale(0.1,0.1,kep)
scaleImage(0.1, 0.1, kep)
```

Expected to scale the image to 10%, but remains at 100%. No error is raised, just nothing happens. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I tried to shift the image to filter out other possible issues and this works as expected:

```
setImageOffset(10,10,kep)
```

The image is shifted with 10 points both directions. Only scaling doesn't work.

Comment: According to the [documentation - page 10](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scribus-scripter/latest/scribus-scripter.pdf)  use `kkep.xScale = 0.5`

Comment: No, I tried this too, didn't work, the script crashed.

Comment: Have you tried `kep.xScale = 0.5` also? Note `kep` is the `imagItem` not `kkep`.

Comment: Yes, tried both, no success. But I fount a workaround that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a workaround here:
http://forums.scribus.net/index.php?topic=94.0

In my case:
setProperty(kep, 'imageXScale', xscale)